# How to extend the text under summation symbol without making extra space

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I want to get the following:

[image: What I want to have]

I tried the following

```
\[
   a(i,k) \leftarrow 
   \min\Big\{0, r(k,k) + \sum_{i^{'} | i^{'}\notin \{i,k\}}\max\{0, r(i{'},k)\}\Big\}
\]
```

and got

[image: What I got]

How can I make the part under the summation extend to left and right without making a space between plus and max as in the first figure?

Comment: Such a formula should be between `\[` and `\]`, rather than `$\displaystyle` and `$`: if set inline it will spoil the appearance of the page.

Comment: Thanks. But even within the brackets (no inline), I can't remove the extra spaces.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that I forgot the extra bracket at the end, I will correct it.

Comment: For any future visitors that want to do this in a LaTeX-like environment that doesn't support `mathtools`, you can use a few dozen `\!` negative spacers in a pinch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apart from `\mathclap{…}`, `mathtools` provides a command specifically set for these situations: `\smashoperator{…}`. Which is, more or less, like putting `\mathclap{…}` in both (sub and super scripts). Taking @tohecz advice about `a'|a'`, your code will be like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
   a(i,k) \gets \min\Bigl\{ 0, r(k,k) + \smashoperator{\sum_{i'\notin\{i,k\}}} \max\{0, r(i',k)\} \Bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Which will be like all the other answers. Moreover, that command has an optional argument: `lr`, default one, will smash both sides; `r` only smash the right; and `l` will smash the left. In the examples I will add some text over the operator so you can see how it works (it smashes both).

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can load the package `mathtools` and write:

```
\[
   a(i,k) \leftarrow 
   \min\Big\{0, r(k,k) + \sum_{\mathclap{i'\mid i'\notin \{i,k\}}}
   \max\{0, r(i',k)\}\Big\}
\]
```

However, I always prefer *some* space left around such sum:

[image]

```
\[
   a(i,k) \leftarrow 
   \min\Big\{0, r(k,k) + \;\sum_{\mathclap{i'\mid i'\notin \{i,k\}}}\;
   \max\{0, r(i',k)\}\Big\}
\]
```

As well:

- Notice that the syntax for the prime is neither `i^{'}` nor `i{'}`. It is `i'`.
- It might be better to use `\mid` instead of `|`. Here, the result is the same, but the symbol `|` has four different meanings (relation, operator, open delim, close delim), and it is a good practice to *always* use one of `\mid`, `\vert`, `\lvert`, `\rvert`.
- In my opinion, `\sum_{i|i\notin X}` is redundant, you can write just `\sum_{i\notin X}`. It is a common practice that summation is over the *very first variable* in the sum's index.
- Typing `\Bigl\{ ... \Bigr\}` instead of `\Big\{...\Big\}` costs two keystrokes more, and you keep the sematics correctly, as well in some cases it is necessary (absolute value `|.|`, reverse-bracket open intervals `].[` etc.)
- You can make the braces after `\max` bigger, it doesn't cost any space and it increases readibility and visual appearance.

[image]

```
\[
   a(i,k) \leftarrow 
   \min\Bigl\{0, r(k,k) + \;\sum_{\mathclap{i'\notin \{i,k\}}}\;
   \max\bigl\{0, r(i{'},k)\bigr\}\Bigr\}
\]
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\mid` instead of `|`; the result here is the same, but it reminds to use it also in text or display style.

Comment: I think you should talk about `\smashoperator{…}` which was designed for this (i.e., it helps if you have to *smash* the subscript and the superscript).

Comment: @Manuel You can post it as a seperate answer I think. I haven't known it even exists so I'll be glad to see an example of its usage.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\mathclap{....}` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
\begin{document}
 \[
   a(i,k) \leftarrow 
   \min\Big\{0, r(k,k) + \sum_{\mathclap{i^{'} | i^{'}\notin \{i,k\}}}\max\{0, r(i{'},k)\}\Big\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]