# ! Undefined control sequence. \[ p(u)= \sum_{v\epsilonN

Tags: undefined

I used the following statement:

```
\[ p(u)= \sum_{v\epsilonN(u)} W(u,v) \]
```

But it shows the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. \[ p(u)= \sum_{v\epsilonN
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It seems `latex` doesn't know about `\epsilonN`. You maybe wanted to write `\epsilon N(u)`, or `\epsilon{}N(u)`? (More details on the reason why in §1.3.3 *LaTeX commands* of the [Not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) - hint, there is no space, number, nor non-letter character between the `\epsilon` and your `N`)

Comment: I'm also not sure whether you want `\epsilon` here. Not sure, do you want the 'is an element of' symbol maybe? That's `\in`

Answer (score 5):

Okay your main problem is, as the error message says, `\epsilonN`. LaTeX doesn't understand that `\epsilonN` is intended to end at the first `n` with `N` being separate. It can't think for itself, you have to tell it what goes with what. Where you have `v\epsilon` the `\` tells LaTeX that a new command starts now, which is how it knows `v` and `\epsilon` are separate. But it doesn't know where the new command ends. You can solve this really simply with `\epsilon N(u)`. Just a space. Spaces are ignored within math mode as far as the output goes, so you can put in as many spaces as you like and it won't make any difference.

```
$a    bcd    e           f g$
```

Looks just like

```
$abcdefg$
```

[image]

However, I've got a feeling that you're using `\epsilon`, the Greek letter, where what you really want is the set inclusion/'is an element of' symbol

[image]

It's important to use the right symbol, not just so that you get the right shape, but also so that LaTeX applies the correct spacing. Also, just in terms of your code input, you don't want the Greek letter epsilon, you want the symbol for some object being "in" some set. So logically, it makes sense to use a command name that corresponds to the symbol you actually want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  p(u) = \sum_{v \in N(u)} W(u,v)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, as an extra, you may like to try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  p(u) = \smashoperator{\sum_{v \in N(u)}} W(u,v)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get rid of the pretty cavernous spaces around the summation sign, as Manuel recommends [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338483/undefined-control-sequence-pu-sum-v-epsilonn/338497#comment830300_338497). Please note, this requires the `mathtools` package.

Comment: In this case `\smashoperator` from `mathtools` [comes in handy](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91505/21930).

Comment: @Manuel good observation, wasn't really thinking about that! Tell you what, I'll add it in as an option.